# Express-subdomain routing not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been looking for solutions for a couple days now trying to google it and all and now i am here. I am trying to setup subdomains for my app using express-subdomain package. However in the example below the app ALWAYS returns app.get route and skips the other subdomain routes specified. 
I have also in turn added the hosts file url so i know that should not be the issue.

It must be in my code for some reason it always ends up displaying Detect Region route even when accessing oce.localhost:3000.

Please help me :)

Server.js

```
var subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Region routes
var router = express.Router();
var na = require('./routes/region/na.js');
var oce = require('./routes/region/oce.js');

router.use(subdomain('na.localhost', na));
router.use(subdomain('oce.localhost', oce));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Detect Region and send to correct subdomain!');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

routes/region/oce.js

```
var
  express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Your are in OCE Region!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And na.js is pretty much the name as oce.js

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting your subdomains in the `router` variable but you don't tell your app to use it.

You have to do that :

```
app.use(router);
```

You put it in place of your current `app.get`.

---

**Edit**

You could also put your `app.get` after the `app.use(router)` so that it will act as a default route. (When you are neither on `oce` or `na`, it will use it)

---

**Edit after some testing**

Alright I've been able to make it work using [`express-vhost`](https://github.com/tommymessbauer/express-vhost). I just updated your `server.js` like so :

```
var subdomain = require('express-vhost');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Region routes
var router = express.Router();
var na = require('./routes/region/na.js');
var oce = require('./routes/region/oce.js');

subdomain.register('na.localhost', na)
subdomain.register('oce.localhost', oce)

app.use(subdomain.vhost(app.enabled('trust proxy')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Detect Region and send to correct subdomain!');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Alright even after adding that it still has the same problem. It seems to always end up going to the default route.

Comment: I am almost wondering if the package has an issue with it but i dont know, maybe i have to use another package, like vhost except i dont want to separate into separate folders it should all be just one App. Do you recomend any?

Comment: I used `vhost` and it was fine for my needs. But your issue seems strange, I'll take another look at it when I can and let you know.

Comment: @Ninetaineedo Cool let me know, is it possible to perhaps use vhost with the similar setup as i have now?

Comment: I think I have a clue of the issue. Try using `'na.localhost:3000'` instead of `'na.localhost'` and let me know if it works.

Comment: Alright, see my updated answer, I've managed to make it work using another module.